# Problems deploying a cordova app to a real Windows Phone 8.1 device

Tags: windows, cordova, deployment, windows-phone-8.1

I have serious issues deploying my Cordova app to my real Windows Phone 8.1 (Nokia Lumia 6.3). I run Windows 8.1 Pro on a VirtualBox VM and Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 is installed. Building the app worked like a charm but running...

```
cordova run windows --device -- --phone
```

... leads to the following error messages:

> Deploying phone package to device:
>
> C:\Users\TestUser\Kunden\company\testproj\produkte\sencha-cordova\cordova\platforms\windows\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Phone_0.0.1.0_debug_Test\CordovaApp.Phone_0.0.1.0_AnyCPU_debug.appxbundle
>
> Installing application
>
> Fehler: Dieser Vorgang wurde wegen Zeitüberschreitung zurückgegeben. (english: "The process aborted due to timeout.")
>
> ERROR: Error code 2148734208 for command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\AppDeploy\AppDeployCmd.exe with args: /install,C:\Users\Marco\Kunden\company\testproj\produkte\sencha-cordova\cordova\platforms\windows\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Phone_0.0.1.0_debug_Test\CordovaApp.Phone_0.0.1.0_AnyCPU_debug.appxbundle,/targetdevice:de
>
> ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: C:\Users\TestUser\Kunden\company\testproj\produkte\sencha-cordova\cordova\platforms\windows\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
>
> You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

I already registered the phone as a developer phone using phonereg.exe, so that's not the problem. Also the phone is listed under "My computer" as "Windows Phone".

Also running on device out of Visual Studio 2013 doesn't work. Here the error message is:

> Fehler 1   Fehler : DEP6100 : Beim Bootstrapping ist in Stufe 'Verbindung mit Gerät wird hergestellt' der folgende unerwartete Fehler aufgetreten:
>
> SmartDeviceException - Dieser Vorgang wurde wegen Zeitüberschreitung zurückgegeben.    CordovaApp.Phone
>
> Fehler 2   Fehler : DEP6200 : Boostrapping für 'Device' fehlgeschlagen. Das Gerät wurde nicht gefunden. Dieser Vorgang wurde wegen Zeitüberschreitung zurückgegeben.
>
> CordovaApp.Phone

In English:

> Error 1   Error : DEP6100 : While Bootstrapping ist in Stufe 'Verbindung mit Gerät wird hergestellt' the following exception has been thrown:
>
> SmartDeviceException - The process has been aborted due to timeout.   CordovaApp.Phone
>
> Error  2   Error : DEP6200 : Boostrapping for 'Device' failed. The device has not been found. The process has been aborted due to timeout.
>
> CordovaApp.Phone

Has anyone an idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails, try the Tools for Apache Cordova approach -- it does take some work to rearrange your project but in the end you do gain the ability to debug your javascript on the phone (when you finally get it on your phone!).

The downside is that MS does things differently from the Cordova CLI, particularly with respect to plugins. You can still work in the CLI (the files are in bld/Debug/Platforms/windows) if you need to overcome some of the automation that VS + Tools for Apache Cordova supplies.

Comment: Ah, I just did it. Indeed the problem was the virtualbox :-( I gave vmware player (free) a try and now it at least transfers the app to the phone (it closes immediately, but I'll have to debug that later).